# Is haskell possible to read multiple files?

Tags: file, haskell

In this case I try to read two files in a row to print them into list respectively.

```
import System.IO
import Data.List
main = do
    text1 <- readFile "a.txt"
    let aList = map (map read) $ map tail $ filter (\xs -> length xs == 4) $ map words $ lines text1 :: [[Int]] --never mind 
    putStr $ show aList
    text2 <- readFile "b.txt"
    let bList = map tail $ filter (\xs -> length xs == 4) $ map words $ lines text2 
    putStr $ show bList
```

AND a.txt and b.txt are:

```
a 1 1 1
a 2 50 1
a 3 50 50

b 100 11 1 0 40 1
b 100 12 3 1 22 23
b 101 11 1 0 45 1
b 101 12 3 1 28 30
b 102 11 1 0 50 1
```

But it seems like by using readFile/ withFile and whatsoever, you can only read one File in a do circle, otherwise you get error

```
test.hs:9:14: Parse error in pattern: show
```

(9:14 is : putStr $ show aList)

Guys what I want to know is do I understand it wrong, or there is another way to access sevaral files once?

Comment: A parse error (which means the syntax is wrong) has nothing to do with the ability to perform the task. Take time to phrase titles (and questions) appropriately.

Comment: where does `stopsList` and `linesList` come from ?

Comment: oh that should be aList and bList, forget changing them here

Comment: No such error in this code. [Demo](http://ideone.com/djw7AD).  Please post your real code.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks, I changed my code to be more specific. Sadly, there is indeed such error occured when I run it. And take any of one readFile code will successfully run.

Comment: There is an error in the code you are trying to run, but not in the code you have posted. Diff them.

Comment: @user3689497 Is that really the code you're trying to run, straight copy and pasted? It sounds like you rewrote it here, which would explain why there's a syntax error in your own code but not here.

Comment: Check to see if you have any tabs in your code. That can mess the spacing up, introducing syntax errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you have a tabs vs. spaces problem, as I can reproduce your error message by indenting

```
    text2 <- readFile "b.txt"
```

more than the previous line.  Unless you're completely sure what you are doing, make sure your file contains only spaces, no tabs.  And then make sure all the lines in your `do` block are indented the same.